# Byte > String > Byte > File VB

Tags: vb.net, string, byte, arrays

I would like to convert byte to string and back, I've tried this:

```
Public Class Form1

        Private Sub Form1_Load(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
            Dim bytes() As Byte = My.Computer.FileSystem.ReadAllBytes("C:\Archive.zip")

            Dim filestream As System.IO.FileStream = System.IO.File.Create("C:\Archive2.zip")

            Dim info As Byte() = fromstringtobyte(frombytetostring(bytes))
            filestream.Write(info, 0, info.Length)
            filestream.Close()
        End Sub
        Private Function frombytetostring(ByVal b() As Byte)
            Dim s As String
            s = Convert.ToBase64String(b)
            Return s

        End Function
        Private Function fromstringtobyte(ByVal s As String)
            Dim b() As Byte
            b = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(s)
            Return b
        End Function
    End Class
```

The new file that was created was corrupted.
Can you please recommend any other solutions?

Sorry for my bad English, it ain't my main language.

Answer (score 0):

Your byte to string conversion is wrong. You need to use:

```
System.Text.Encoding.[your encoding].GetString(bytes)
```

Source:

[How to: Convert an Array of Bytes into a String in Visual Basic](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms172827.aspx)

[How to: Convert Strings into an Array of Bytes in Visual Basic](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms172828.aspx)

---

You might want to read this as well to decide which encoding to use: [The Absolute Minimum Every Software Developer Absolutely, Positively Must Know About Unicode and Character Sets (No Excuses!)](http://www.joelonsoftware.com/articles/Unicode.html)

Comment: How do i know which encoding to use?

Comment: You need to use the same encoding in both your string to byte and byte to string. Which one you choose depends on various factors. See the link I posted.

Comment: What link did you post?

Answer (score -1):

I've found an answer, the new code is:

```
Public Class Form1

    Private Sub Form1_Load(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
        Dim bytes() As Byte = My.Computer.FileSystem.ReadAllBytes("C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Repair Pro\Windows Repair Pro (All In One) 3.8.7\Tweaking.com - Windows Repair Portable\Archive.zip")

        Dim filestream As System.IO.FileStream = System.IO.File.Create("C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Repair Pro\Windows Repair Pro (All In One) 3.8.7\Tweaking.com - Windows Repair Portable\Archive2.zip")

        Dim info As Byte() = fromstringtobyte(frombytetostring(bytes))
        filestream.Write(info, 0, info.Length)
        filestream.Close()
    End Sub
    Private Function frombytetostring(ByVal b() As Byte)
        Dim s As String
        s = BitConverter.ToString(b)
        Return s.Replace("-", "")
    End Function
    Private Function fromstringtobyte(ByVal s As String)
        Dim B() As Byte = New Byte(s.Length / 2 - 1) {}
        For i As Integer = 0 To s.Length - 1 Step 2
            B(i / 2) = Convert.ToByte(s.Substring(i, 2), 16)
        Next
        Return B
    End Function

End Class
```